# How to read an char argv input and parse(check) it for non-integers

Tags: c++, parsing, command-line, error-handling, char

say my command line is `a.out -a 3eF6`

If I access argv[2], it will give me 3eF6 (which I think this is an array of chars?) 
How would I loop through this to check that every single char is an integer, and not an alpha value like 'e' or 'F'?

How/Would I turn it into a string?

I know that if I do `a = atoi(argv[2])`, where `argv[2]` is 32, then a = 32. 
I also know that if `argv[2]` is 3eF6, then the following will NOT result in "wrong input".

```
 a = 0;
 a = atoi(argv[2])
if( a = 0 )
 cout << "wrong input";
```

Instead, `a` will be evaluated to 3. So it only reads the first integer in this instance, but I want to be able to access the whole argument, 3eF6.

I've tried using atoi(getline(argv[2], a), or something equivalent, but for some reason I get an error that says I cannot convert a string to const char.

Anyway, how would I convert argv[2] to a string which I could parse? Or how could I access each char in argv[2]?

I've also tried:

```
string string1 = argv[i+1] // argv[i] is an option like -a
```

but upon running the program with arguments, I get this error:

```
./a.out -b 2 -a 2 -s 2 -t 8
```

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
>   what():  basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid
>   Abort (core dumped)

Comment: I'd use `lexical_cast`, which will throw an exception if part of the string can't be converted. If you can't do that, I'd probably do the conversion with `strtol`. That lets you get a pointer to first character it could not convert. In your case, you want to check that it's pointing to the string's NUL terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I created a char pointer that holds my char command line element:

```
char* charString = argv[i+1];
```

and passed it to a function to parse

```
parser(charString);
```

In this case, argv[i+1] is equivalent to argv[2] in my question.
The function definition of my parser function looks like this:

```
    void parser(char* charString){
        for(int i=0; charString[i] != '\0'; i++){
                bool isAlpha = isalpha(charString[i]);
                bool isPunct = ispunct(charString[i]);
                if ((isAlpha == true)||(isPunct == true)){
                        printError();
                        exit(1);
                } else;
           }
     }
```

Important to note is that to end parsing at the end of the char array, you **cannot** do

```
for(int i=0; charString[i] < sizeof(charString); i++){
```

as the array size will always return 8 or 9. Instead, you must end parsing when the character evaluated is equal to '\0', or in other words parse while the character charString[i] is not equal to '\0'.

Answer (score 1):

```
TCHAR c;
int n(0);
int x(0);
int y(0);

for (x = 0; x < argc; ++x)
{
    // Loop through each character in the argument.
    n = _tcslen(argv[x]);
    for (y = 0; y < n; ++y)
    {
        c = argv[x][y];
        if (isdigit(c))
        {
            cout << c << "is a digit" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << c << "is not a digit" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```